# Resultados dos teste não aparecem no navegador - grunt-karma

Tags: javascript, angularjs, grunt

Estou usando grunt e karma para fazer os testes do meu projeto. Mas quando uso o comando grunt test, os resultados não aparecem no navegador e nem na linda de comando.

A única coisa que aparece é o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é o meu arquivo karma.conf.js:`// Karma configuration
// Generated on Mon Mar 31 2014 10:21:42 GMT-0300 (E. South America Standard Time)

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: './',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine','requirejs'],


// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [

  'app/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js', 
  'app/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js', 
  'app/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js', 
  'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',      
  'app/scripts/*.js',
  'app/scripts/**/*.js',
  'test/spec/**/*.js'
],

  plugins: [
        'karma-junit-reporter',
        'karma-chrome-launcher',
        'karma-firefox-launcher',
        'karma-jasmine',
        'karma-requirejs'
    ],    


// list of files to exclude
exclude: [

],

// web server port
port: 9876,


// enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
colors: true,

reporters: ['dots'],


// level of logging
// possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,


// enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
autoWatch: false,

    browserNoActivityTimeout: 10000,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Firefox'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

O meu arquivo de teste:

```
describe('Controller: MainCtrl', function () {

  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('AbsenteismoApp'));

  var MainCtrl,
    scope;

  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    MainCtrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
      $scope: scope
    });
  }));

  it('deve verificar o tamanho do array expressao scope', function () {
    expect(scope.expressao.length).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

O que será testado:

```
 'use strict';

angular.module('AbsenteismoApp')
    .controller('MainCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){

        $scope.expressao = [];
  }]);
```

No prompt de comando aparece essa mensagem:

> WARN [Firefox 27.0.0 (Windows 7)]: Disconnected (1 times), because no
>   message in  10000 ms.

Comment: Estás a correr isto localmente ou remotamente (SauceLabs/BrowserStack)? Podes dar um link para o Git?

Answer (score 2):

Você está usando o plugin do Require.js; então, vai ser necessário **inicializar manualmente os testes**.

Caso você não vá utilizar o Require.js, recomendo que remova as referências do seu arquivo de configuração pois o plugin altera o comportamento padrão do Karma.

Na minha aplicação, faço da seguinte forma, utilizando como base um arquivo gerado pelo próprio Karma:

```
require.config({
    // Carrega todos os testes
    deps: testFiles,

    paths: ...,
    shim: ...,

    // Inicializa os testes
    callback: window.__karma__.start
});
```

E, no arquivo de configuração:

```
files: [
    "portal/js/require/require.config.js",
    "test/modules/cic/unit-main.js",
    { pattern: "js/**/*.js", included: false },
    { pattern: "test/libs/*.js", included: false },
    { pattern: "test/unit/**/*.spec.js", included: false }
],
```

Os patterns que estão com o `included: false` serão *apenas* servidos pelo servidor HTTP do Karma, mas não terão as tags script incluídas na página. Assim, o Require.js fica encarregado destes.

Answer (score 1):

Para o Karma fechar o Browser precisa de ter o SingleRun ligado. Na própria descrição que tem no código:

```
// Continuous Integration mode  - Modo de integração continuo
// if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits  - caso true o Karma abre, corre testes e fecha o browser
```

Assim mude para:

```
singleRun: true
```